# How to prevent OData from removing EntitySet objects from calculated properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net, odata

In a case where the calculated field has a EntitySet value within it, how do you auto expand it on OData. If you try to use the regular expanding methods, it will through an error as this field can not be queried from the database (which is obvious as its a calculated value).

As of right now, `ObjectA` gets show in OData but `EntitySetB` within `ObjectA` does not. `EntitySetB` needs to be an entity set as in my use case as I do also call this Entity Set by guid and filter against it.

```
class EntitySetA
{
    public ObjectA? ObjectA
    {
        get
        {        
//Get code            
        }
        set
        {
            
        }
    }
}

class ObjectA
{
...
    public EntitySetB? EntitySetB { get; set;}
...
}
```

Comment: Read following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/backing-field?tabs=data-annotations

Comment: That document around modelling seems to be more tailored the database side and not so much for OData. I tried to add the BackingField to ObjectA but no luck

Comment: The link is for Entity.  Entity is the front end of the database connection.  What didn't work with backingField?  Did you use both Get and Set.  Get doesn't work without a Set.

Comment: The issue is more of OData side. The data does get pulled out fine but OData actively removes the data when returning the data via the OData endpoint.

Comment: OData does not remove the data if it is coming from the database.  There is a mapping between the c# classes and the database.  Maybe the mapping need to be refreshed.

Comment: OData does remove it if it is an Entity Type as it expects an expands. In this case, I am manually Including the data. I can see the other fields being populated but I can not see this one as OData seems to remove it in the middleware as I assume it wants an explicit expands

Comment: That is why I think it is the mapping.

Comment: I have break pointed certain bits of the code and when the data come back from the database, it includes the data I am expecting. To test, I 
1) I use EF core to pull the data as a queryable
2) Use Include to include the extra tables
3) break point in the controller to see the data includes the values i expect
4) Return the queryable up to odata which then removes it. 

I am currently having this issue with JSON values which is can deserialise with all the data and OData removes it when you can the HTTP endpoint

Comment: Is you issue at frontend of backend?  It sounds like you backend connection is Entity and your front end is a HTTP Connection.  The backend is working correctly.  I can't tell if your controller is in the client or server (or both).  It sound like the HTTP Server is getting data from database and should be serializing the data to json and sending a response to the client.  Than the client should be receiving the response and then deserialize the json.  I can't tell from what you posted if the issue is at the server serializing the data or at the client deserializing the data.

Comment: Its on the server side (the controller with the OData plugin). If the OData controller endpoint returns a database queryable with the included objects, before it returns it to OData middleware, it has the data I expect. But after it goes through the OData middleware and returns it to the client (via postman for example) it removes the data. If that data is not explicitly "expanded", OData it seems to remove it. It shows up before going through the OData middleware but disappears afterwards.

Comment: Did you try to update the mapping using Migration?

Comment: The DB mapping isn't the issue as the data that I am expecting to be expanded in calculated. The data that goes into the calculated property shows up in OData endpoint fine, but any Entity Type the calculated property references does not show up (refer to the example code above). If I break point the controller and inspect the calculated property, I can see the values there but OData strips it out.

Comment: Entity and Controllers are two different interfaces.  Entity is interface of a database.  Controller is an interface for a HTTP Request/Response.   Some applications use a Controller for the Front End between client and server and then use Entity for backend between server and database.  You seem to be having a backend issue and refreshing the mapping using Migration may solve issue.

Comment: It is 100% not a EF issue, as I mentioned before, it shows the data exactly how I expect it to be when I break point it. Only after its returned in the controller and OData middleware is used (if I remove OData from the endpoint, I can see it exactly how I expect it to be) it removes the Entity Type from the calculated field. 
I need to expanded explicitly which causes issue on IQuerayable as it try to do a SQL query even though its a calculated field. A bad fix I tested was to replace IQueryable with an IList instead and that did resolve it but that is, of course, very slow on larger queries

Comment: If the data is correct at the controller the issue has to be in the backend.

Comment: How can the issue be in the backend when the data at the controller is correct but when you call the endpoint via postman, I can see the data being obfuscated. And when I removed the OData attributes to the endpoint and keep everything else the same, I can see the data I am expected in the same postman query.

Comment: I think you have a two port application.  Port 1 is a HTTP connection from the client to the server.  The server has a Controller (A Listener) which receives the HTTP Request. Port 2 is a connection from the server to a database to store the data.  Since data is received in Port 1, the issue is Port 2 which is the backend.

Comment: No, its all in one server. The controller on the server has the data but when the controller finishes and goes through its middleware, it is stripped out due to the OData middleware. The data is coming out fine from the database. I can verify that 100% without any issues. The controller, when call the database via EF, gets the data fine. Once this data is given to OData middleware (using the [EnableQuery] Attribute) the data then gets removed. Same code without the OData middleware shows the data without any issues.

Comment: An HTTP connection always has two parts and client and server and it doesn't matter if they are on same machine or different machines.  There is always a connection.  I keep on saying it is a mapping issue in the middleware.  The mapping needs to be updated so what is returned from database gets put into the c# classes.

Comment: And I keep saying from what I have tested the mapping from the database to my C# object is perfectly fine. OData removes itself as it expects to query the object itself. I am looking for an OData configuration change to prevent the removal of this one particular field. The mapping from one object to another is perfectly fine. 

The issue is when its an IQuerable object, it tries to run a SQL query to call a calculated field which would obviously will fail. I simply want it to not run the SQL query at all or AutoExpand this field without running any SQL query against it.

Comment: What about adding code in the Get/Set properties of the class?

Comment: The calculated field that is having issues is a property with a code that creates the object from other fields that comes from the Db.

Comment: The calculation must then be wrong.

Comment: But I put a break point in and it shows at the return statement the value I am expecting. The OData middleware it removing it as from what I can see, its expecting the fields to be "expanded" (which I mentioned before can not be done against a calculated property like this as it will be using IQueryable and OData will try to use SQL to get the data that is calculated on the fly).

Comment: A calculated value will never enter the GET/SET.  You need to do the calculation some place else like in one of the other GET/SET.

Comment: Removing the OData queryable, it seems to enter fine. Or even converting the object from IQueryable to IList, it seems to enter fine. Only issue is if I use OData with the IQueryable object, it fails as I mentioned before, it trys to expand this property via SQL. I want OData to ideally ignore the SQL query and not remove the data (leave it in a default expanded state if possible).

Comment: May be use a Raw SQL : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7b24d9a2-4819-4850-9188-6191612e7780/odata-web-api-using-ef?forum=aspwebapi